# Create a table using session variable in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, session-variables

I want to create a table with `username`.

So I have started this session on login page. Given below SQL query is on another page, i have session started over here also. I have kept a `if` statement, if submitted the query will run or else  `mysqli_error()`. 
The content on the page gets submitted and reflects in database but the table is not getting created.

```
 $t = "CREATE TABLE uname = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."' (
                                year DATE,
                                area_s FLOAT,
                                maxp FLOAT,
                                minp FLOAT,
                                area_e FLOAT,
                                volume FLOAT,
                                percent_change FLOAT
                                )";
                                $u = mysqli_query($dbc,$t);
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `"CREATE TABLE ".$_SESSION['user_name']."`